# Firebase.Database.Query Cannot resolve method 'on(?,?)'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a datareference to my `database` on `Firebase`. SetValue, `onChildAddedListeners` etc all work as intended.
But on() just does not work for database.query! I can't seem to find ANY topic on this either. What incredibly silly mistake am I making here...?

[image: image of error :(]

UNREAL!

I've read the documentations [on firebase.database.Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on)

I have these imports as well

```
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the JavaScript API with the Android API here - for Android you need to use one of the below to attach listeners to a `Query` or `DatabaseReference`.

> **addChildEventListener(ChildEventListener listener)**
> Add a listener for child events occurring at this location.
>
> **addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListener listener)**
> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.
>
> **addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener listener)**
> Add a listener for changes in the data at this location.

See the Android version of [firebase.database.Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query).

Comment: Thanks Grimthorr! Silly me... argh!